# Can't getName from CategoryCollection while getId and getUrl work

Tags: magento2, category, collection

I cant seem to get Category name while i can Get Id and URL am i doing something wrong?

**Layout (catalog_product_view.xml)**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.category" template="productCategory.phtml"/>
```

**Template**

```
<?php 
  $_product = $block->getProduct();
  $categoryCollection = $_product->getCategoryCollection();

  foreach ($categoryCollection as $value) {
      echo $value->getUrl(); // This returns correct Urls
      echo $value->getId(); //This return correct Ids
      echo $value->getName(); // This returns Null
  }
  ?>
```

**EDIT**

Have tried and not showing `null`

```
$value->getData()
$value->getPath()
$value->getParentCategory()->getName()
```

I'm finding this very confusing, as how i can return almost anything except name

Im doing this in magento 2.

Comment: Is this magento 2 or magento 1? Because it seems to be magento 1

Comment: @Andre its magento 2 i just want to show categories of current product on its page, so i tried to go with something simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$categoryCollection = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

foreach ($categoryCollection as $value) {

      echo $value->getUrl(); // This returns correct Urls
      echo $value->getId(); //This return correct Ids
      echo $value->getName(); // Will return the proper name
}
```

This way you won't have to load anything in a loop.

Comment: Just a question why isnt the name included in Collection?

Comment: In general, the sql query associated to a collection is executed only on the base table of the entity. In this case `catalog_category_entity`. For flat entities it retrieves every field, but for EAV collections you have to add the attributes you need by hand, to avoid performance issues. See how the [`getCategoryCollection` method looks](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php#L421)